# How to get all column data from two tables by using leftJoin in Yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I tried to get `books.id` and `authors.Name` in an array using `leftJoin()` in Yii2.

```
$data = Book::find()
       ->select("authors.Name, books.id")
       ->leftJoin("authors", "authors.book_id = books.id")
       ->where(['books.id' => '14,16,17,18'])
       ->all();
```

But this result is only from `books` table. I can not see `authors.Name` in this result.

In Laravel, it is easy to get the data like the above. Is it not possible in Yii2?

Comment: Might not be relevant to your question but here's a typo in your example above - the first argument (`authors`) to `leftJoin` is not quoted. I assume this is supposed to be a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `all()` returns array of related models and usually this models is not able to represent result of such query (for example `Book` model does not have `Name` field). Usually it is better to use [`asArray()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait#asArray()-detail) - then `all()` will return list of arrays (which can store any kind of key-value pairs returned by query) instead of AR objects:

```
$data = Book::find()
    ->select('authors.Name, books.id')
    ->leftJoin('authors', 'authors.book_id = books.id')
    ->where(['books.id' => '14,16,17,18'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "{$data['id']} - {$data['Name']}\n";
}
```

Or use [`Query`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query) directly:

```
$data = (new Query())
    ->select('authors.Name, books.id')
    ->from(Book::tableName())
    ->leftJoin('authors', 'authors.book_id = books.id')
    ->where(['books.id' => '14,16,17,18'])
    ->all();

foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "{$data['id']} - {$data['Name']}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your select clause  `->select("authors.Name, books.id")` you have not the columns  `authors.id` and then the columns is not retrived  from db.

so try adding this column too
and do the fact you have another id referer to the columns using a proper  alias eg:  autors_id

```
$data = Book::find()
       ->select("authors.Name, books.id, authors.id as authors_id")
       ->leftJoin(authors, "authors.book_id = books.id")
       ->where(['books.id' => '14,16,17,18'])
       ->all()
```

and be sure you have the same exact name  for authors  column name (normally the column name is lowercase )

```
 ->select("authors.name as authors_name, books.id, authors.id as authors_id")
```

amd be sure you have a correspondant field for receive the select result for author_name and author_id

Comment: sorry, @scaisEdge.It's my typo. What i want to get is "authors.Name", not "authors.id". I fixed it in my question. so, can you give me another answer for this correct question?

Comment: @IgorCarvalho  answer  updated ..  let me know .. eventually show me the code where you access to the result

Comment: This answer does not make any sense. If `Book` models does not have `Name` or `authors_id` fields such modifications in `select()` will not change anything. This is not even valid PHP code...